# Decoding a video on the fly in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using the Android ExoPlayer to play a video, but I want to implement some custom encoding mechanism.

The idea is to change certain bytes on the video file, so that it's not playable from standard players. And then in ExoPlayer perform the decoding on the fly (without actually modifying the stored file).

How could I do such a thing - using a custom DataSource? Any tips on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: yes, create a custom `DataSource` - for example see `FileDataSource.java` or `AssetDataSource.java` or similar source files

Comment: @pskink thanks, I will take a look at these.

Comment: all you would need to change is `public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) throws FileDataSourceException {` method

Comment: @pskink that worked, unfortunately the original FineDataSource is declared final, so I cannot extend it, but had to copy the whole class. But it's not a big deal, it's important that it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sure, your welcome